# Is there any utility under Ubuntu for switching groups of keyboard layouts?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, localization

For example: i write a text which requires constant switching between russian and english layouts, but when i'm doing something else i need another pair/group of layouts(russian and ukrainian, etc). Is there anything to group layouts in such way?

Comment: I think there's an option under either Keyboard or Language support.

Answer (score 0):

Change the keyboard layout. [This page](http://linux.about.com/od/ubuntu_doc/a/ubudg19t7.htm) also has desktop index option with a lot of good information.

You could try a different workstation (I think it's on the bottom).